# Start WebStorm with files/tabs from last session

Tags: webstorm

I want Webstorm to start with the files/tabs, which were open when I quit Webstorm the last time. Where do I find this setting? I'm using Webstorm 11.

Comment: That's exactly what WebStorm does: 1) It re-opens your last project (this option can be disabled) 2) On project open it re-opens files that were opened before closing project. It has always been like that -- no special configuration is required. Are you opening it on another computer? Or keeping files on some removable/network device? If IDE cannot access files it just closes such editor tabs automatically.

Comment: Deleting the `.idea` folder helped (because by default the option is activated as you told). Maybe the settings were corrupt because of a blue screen.. -.- Thank you!

Comment: BSOD/computer crash or hard restart while IDE is running could easily lead to config files corruption (both project settings and IDE-wide settings) regardless of the OS/file system used. You better have periodical backups of such folders. **P.S.** Consider answering your own question -- it may be useful for other people in similar situation (answered question has higher priority in search results + more likely to be read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the folder `MYPROJECT/.idea` solved my problem.

@LazyOne pointed out correctly, that WebStorm starts with the files from the last session by default. My configration files might have been corrupt because of a blue screen which occured yesterday.